# Jetpack Compose vector parsing issue

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I'm trying to load a vector but keep getting this error stack trace

```
 java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown command for: R
    at androidx.compose.ui.graphics.vector.PathNodeKt.toPathNodes(PathNode.kt:275)
    at androidx.compose.ui.graphics.vector.PathParser.addNode(PathParser.kt:525)
    at androidx.compose.ui.graphics.vector.PathParser.parsePathString(PathParser.kt:84)
    at androidx.compose.ui.graphics.vector.VectorKt.addPathNodes(Vector.kt:72)
    at androidx.compose.ui.graphics.vector.compat.XmlVectorParser_androidKt.parsePath(XmlVectorParser.android.kt:279)
    at androidx.compose.ui.graphics.vector.compat.XmlVectorParser_androidKt.parseCurrentVectorNode(XmlVectorParser.android.kt:101)
    at androidx.compose.ui.res.VectorResources_androidKt.loadVectorResourceInner(VectorResources.android.kt:81)
    at androidx.compose.ui.res.VectorResources_androidKt.vectorResource(VectorResources.android.kt:62)
    at androidx.compose.ui.res.VectorResources_androidKt.vectorResource(VectorResources.android.kt:52)
    at com.tapmax.football.ui.screens.design.DesignScreenKt$KitPager$1.invoke(DesignScreen.kt:440)
    at com.tapmax.football.ui.screens.design.DesignScreenKt$KitPager$1.invoke(DesignScreen.kt:439)
```

I couldnt copy in the full code of my vector so i've attached an image, its just a normal vector

[image]

Comment: It is not preferable to not use larger images as vectorImage as it takes more time to render than the bitmap version.

Answer (score 2):

Your compiler warnings might complain about a `RESOURCE_TOO_LONG` (some path value). It seems there's a maximum for those.

The parser opens the string value, finds the `R` and doesn't know what to do with it.

You can either:

- simplify the XML (or the source material you used to generate it).
- split that path into two paths (probably adding a `Z` IIRC at the end of the first path to close it, and a `M<last_coordinate>` to the second to start from where it left). But really it'd be better to have a compliant source to start with :)